# Unable to change the color of action bar in the app

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-fragments

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fniw1q9lx2U8D5CblZHAdBrOl2Oais0T/view?usp=sharing

I want to change the color of my action bar in the dark mode as you can see in the picture which i have attached contains a black action bar behind the "Happy Birthday" !

Comment: can you share your themes /styles

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1H3RLhxWxe5T3_BacBCkbsDMavt4QWPto/view?usp=sharing

Comment: The above one is the manifest and second one is the theme

Comment: is your phone is in dark mode?

Comment: yes .. i want to change in dark mode

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For `Dark Mode`, android looks at the styles and themes defined in the `themes.xml` file under the following directory

```
res/values-night/themes.xml
```

By default, in `Light Mode` the default action bar will use your base application theme's `colorPrimary` defined inside `res/values/themes.xml`. Which is `@color/white` in your case.

By default, in `Dark Mode` the default action bar  will always be black and will not use the `colorPrimary` defined inside `res/values-night/themes.xml`

**Solution :**
We need to force the action bar to use the `colorPrimary` attribute of our night theme or any separate color from `colors.xml`.

**1. If you want to depend on `colorPrimay`**

- Apply this style `Widget.MaterialComponents.ActionBar.Primary` to your action bar inside your night theme using `actionBarStyle` attribute

**res/values-night/themes.xml**

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Theme.HappyBirthday" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_200</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/black</item>
        <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_200</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
        <!-- Status bar color. -->
        <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>

        <!-- Applying style like this  -->
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.ActionBar.Primary</item>
    </style>
    
</resources>
```

**2. If you want to use separate color from `color.xml`**

- Create a new style `MyActionBarDarkStyle` inside `res/values-night/themes.xml` that extend from `Widget.MaterialComponents.ActionBar.Primary`
- Override the `background` attribute with any color
- Apply the new style to your action bar inside your night theme using `actionBarStyle` attribute

**res/values-night/themes.xml**

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Theme.HappyBirthday" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_200</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/black</item>
        <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_200</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
        <!-- Status bar color. -->
        <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>

        <!-- Applying the new style that is defined below  -->
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBarDarkStyle</item>
    </style>

    <!-- Our new style for ActionBar -->
    <style name="MyActionBarDarkStyle" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.ActionBar.Primary">
         <item name="background">@color/warm_yellow</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you said, it is in Dark Mode, so you need to handle it also.

First. create a folder named `values-night` .

[image]

And then, you need to COPY `colors.xml` (from folder `values`) and PASTE inside the folder `values-night`.

Finally, change the collor at `colors.xml` for `values-night` as for Dark Mode.

Comment: But why to make another folder it already contains 2 themes i.e. one for dark and another for the light ... and also the color changes in the light mode but not in dark !

Comment: @SarthakGupta can you update your question also including your files that you mention

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1gVKyQuXY-iZlt12vcDlYbF21Q718SJyz?usp=sharing           This is my whole work !

Comment: @SarthakGupta I already checked it, since the folder already created. Just copy the `color.xml` inside that folder. Do you understand?

Comment: why to copy bro ..... as everything is given by default i am just asking the syntax or code for changing it

Comment: You can edit everything in the app --> res --> values folder in the android studio !