# Action bar color is always black?

Tags: android

I generated a project in Android Studio, and wish to support day and night theme. Android studio generates two `themes.xml` files, one for day and night theme respectively. However, I can't seem to get the action bar color to be anything except black when in night theme. It works perfectly in day theme by adjusting `colorPrimary`. Here is my `themes.xml` for my dark theme.

```xml
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Theme.MyApp" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_500</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/black</item>
        <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_200</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
        <!-- Status bar color. -->
        <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/purple_200</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: Found the answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68241378/unable-to-change-the-color-of-action-bar-in-the-app